# Call function into another function with in the same Controller Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, function

I am new to using angularjs and i have declared a two functions in controller, and now i want to use one function into another function how can i do that 
means if i say function name into another function it says Undefined.

here is the code:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('customer').controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$state', 'Sservice',
  function($scope, $state, Sservice) {

    var that = this;

    (function getDetails() {
        //IMPLEMENTATION
    }());

    this.function2 = function function2 (id){
        //implementation
      getDetails(); // says undefined
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: i just wan to know how to call a function inside another function in the same controller

Comment: `function a() { b(); }`.

Comment: i have added code to my question can you check and please tell me where i went wrong?

Answer (score 13):

```js
.controller('SampleController',function($scope){
$scope.funcA = function(){
   $scope.funcB();//scope level function
   funcC(); //non scope level function``
}
$scope.funcB = function(){
}
var funcC = function(){
}
});
```

Comment: but my functions are not in $scope

Comment: Can you share the controller structure

Answer (score 3):

Worked best for me

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope',function($scope)
 {
$scope.functionA=function(){
alert("Inside functionA")
$scope.functionB();  
};          
$scope.functionB=function(){            
alert("Inside functionB");  
}
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<input type="button" value="Click to call functionA" ng-click="functionA()">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
.controller('SampleController',function($scope){
$scope.funcA = function(){
   $scope.funcB();//scope level function
   funcC(); //non scope level function``
}
$scope.funcB = function(){
}
var funcC = function(){
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve exactly, but you can simply declare your two functions as

```
function getDetails() {
    //IMPLEMENTATION
}

this.function2 = function(id) {
    getDetails(); 
};
```

Comment: getDetails is global function it will execute when controller is loaded 

function2 is executes when user clicks on button

i want to execute getDetails function when user clicks on button i.e.  i want to call getDetails in function2
i tried the same logic which you pasted above but it says undefined

Comment: No, getDetail() is not a global function. It's only visible from the controller function. And function2() will call it if you declare it as I did in my answer. Post the updated code in your question, post all the other relevant code, and post the complete and exact error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things complex. Simply, do like this

```
'use strict';
angular.module('customer').controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$state', 'Sservice',
      function($scope, $state, Sservice) {

        function getDetails() {
            //IMPLEMENTATION
        };

        function function2 (id){
            //implementation
          getDetails(); // says undefined
        };
      }
]);
```

Comment: you are not understanding what i am asking for

 
getDetails is global function it will execute when controller is loaded function2 is executes when user clicks on button i want to execute getDetails function when user clicks on button i.e. i want to call getDetails in function2

Comment: `getDetails` will be declared (not globally, privately in the controller) and will not be called until you invoke `function2`.

Comment: If my understanding is correct - You can to call getDetails() at the time of execution of controller and also when function2 is called. Please confirm

Answer (score 0):

Several areas of code are confused in your example above. For a start, `function2` is not declared properly.

You've wrapped your `getDetails` function into what is known as a [self-executing anonymous function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/). This means it is not visible to code outside the SEAF wrapper, including `function2`. Omit the SEAF wrapper so `getDetails` is defined when `function2` wants to use it.

Finally, you are using Angular but assigning `function2` to `this` on the controller. This is probably not what you wanted to do; functions that you want to expose to the HTML should be attached to `$scope`, not `this`.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('customer').controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$state', 'Sservice',
  function($scope, $state, Sservice) {

    function getDetails() {
        //IMPLEMENTATION
    }

    $scope.function2 = function(id) {
        //implementation
        getDetails();
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
My these options below could help

'use strict';
angular.module('customer').controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$state', 'Sservice',
  function($scope, $state, Sservice) {

    function getDetails() {
        //IMPLEMENTATION
    };

    function function2 (id){
        //implementation
      getDetails(); // says undefined
    };
  }
]);


or 

'use strict';
angular.module('customer').controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$state', 'Sservice',
  function($scope, $state, Sservice) {

    $scope.getDetails = function() {
        //IMPLEMENTATION
    };

    $scope.function2 = function(id){
        //implementation
      $scope.getDetails(); // says undefined
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Work fine for me:

```
{
    // define angular module/app

    var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);

    // create angular controller and pass in $scope and $http
    function formController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.sitelist = function(){
            $http.get("http://mars.ourgoogle.in/clients/techinfini/customcms/index.php/Ajax/sitelist").then(function(items){    
            console.log(items.data);
            $scope.list = items.data;       
        }); 
    }

    // process the form
    $scope.processForm = function() {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'http://mars.ourgoogle.in/clients/techinfini/customcms/index.php/Ajax/angulartest',
            data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).success(function(data) {
                $scope.sitelist();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot find name '$scope'